# Excluding Google Maps, What is the best way to Geo Code 1000+ addresses in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, geolocation, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I have to Geo Code 1000s of addresses to obtain Lats and Longs so that I can later run some data and geo analysis on those addresses.

In the past, I used Google's API to obtain this information, however, now Google requires Credit card information to generate API key. Even then it has limit of about 60 address per hour or per day (can't remember exact limit).

I was wondering if someone can guide me how to go about obtaining Lat and Long for 1000s of address with python?

Comment: you can refer here https://gist.github.com/shanealynn/033c8a3cacdba8ce03cbe116225ced31

Comment: Thanks but is there any other way besides using Google maps?

Answer (score 2):

SmartyStreets has [a tool for that.](https://smartystreets.com/products/list)

SmartyStreets also has a [Python SDK](https://smartystreets.com/docs/sdk/python) you can use. You can look up thousands of addresses in seconds or less.

Full disclosure: I am a software developer for SmartyStreets, and I wrote the Python SDK

Comment: :-D 

I should have added "Open Source" or "Free", because otherwise I was happy to go with google maps

Comment: Ah. Yeah, SmartyStreets lets you do a free subscription of 250 lookups per month, but if you want a lot at once, it is not free. :)

Answer (score 1):

geopy is an open-source Python 2 and 3 client for several popular geocoding web services. To name a few: Here, MapBox, Nominatim, Arcgis, Geonames, TomTom. Check the complete list with usage examples:

https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.geocoders

Some of them require an API Key to be passed as an argument. Others, don't. For example, Nominatim only requires defining a `user_agent` for your App.

Installation via PyPi

```
pip install geopy
```

https://pypi.org/project/geopy/